# saving a file from a database using JFileChooser

Tags: java, database, io, jfilechooser

I wanted to ask, how to download a file from a database and save it Using Jfilechooser. Can you give me some idea how this would work ?

```
koneksi_db();
JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser();
fs.setDialogTitle("save a file");
int result = fs.showSaveDialog(null);

try {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from file where nama = ?");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        fs.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
        int tampak = fs.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (tampak == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sql error");
}
```

I don't know what should I do after `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`.

Comment: So I guess searching for "write file in java" wasn't successful? I wonder why ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the images are store as BLOB. You should get the binaryStream from the resultset, read it and write into a file in the selected path. For example:

```
try (Connection connection = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
     PreparedStatenent ps = 
            conn.prepareStatement("select image from file where nama = ?")) {

       ps.setXXX() // set the value for 'nama'
       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

       if(rs.next()){
           fs.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
           int tampak = fs.showSaveDialog(null);

           if (tampak == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
               File file = fs.getSelectedFile();
                try (InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
                     OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    while (stream.read(buffer) > 0) {
                            output.write(buffer);
                    }
                }
           }
       }
       rs.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
      // FileNotFoundException handling
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
      // IOException handling
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
     // SQLException handling
    }
}
```

PD: The connections and streams are defined with try with resources for auto close.

Comment: How do you know he likes to write a binary file? How do you know his table structure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you explain what you did and why it would work?

Comment: Tom I don't need know he's table structure. He just want download a file (maybe image, maybe other type of file) from a database.

When you save a image in a database, commonly you convert the image to a byte array for match with the blob column. I assume that's he's case (maybe i'm wrong).

KFitcher Just get the stream/blobk from the database and write it on a file.

PD: Sorry for my english.

Comment: If you guess what OP wants, then you should add that to the answer and like @KFichter wrote (implicitly): explain in your answer what you've did where and why it should/might work. It might also a good idea to close used streams.

Comment: Kind of strange, that the `catch` blocks for handling exceptions during the work with files belongs to the outer `try` block which handles SQL stuff and the inner `try`, which handles files, has no `catch` blocks. Maybe something is wrong here?

Comment: For a better exception handling, the inner try should have a catch block. But, in this case i've skip that. In this case is not neccessary, because the only thing that we need close is the ResultSet but when the PreparedStatement is close, the ResultSet will be closed too. If the inner try fails, the flow go to the catch blocks for exception handling and in this point, the resultset and all streams are closed.